# How to solve the error admob after onRewardedAdClosed()?

Tags: java, android, admob

The ad is showing, but when I click on `close the ad` the error is:

```
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
    #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
```

And actions don't perform in `onRewardedAdClosed()`

Steps:

When starting, I execute:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationComplete: " + initializationStatus);
            }
        });
```

Next:

```
rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
```

Next:

```
RewardedAdCallback adCallback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                    // Ad opened.
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                    // Ad closed.
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedAdClosed: ");

                    fragmentFirst = new FragmentFirst();

                    clipBody = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction clipUnit = clipBody.beginTransaction();

                    clipUnit.add(R.id.container, fragmentFirst, "fragment_first");
                    clipUnit.addToBackStack(null);
                    clipUnit.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                    clipUnit.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
                    // User earned reward.
                    // Load Tasks
                    Log.d(TAG, "onUserEarnedReward: ");

                    // coins++
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int errorCode) {
                    // Ad failed to display
                }
            };
            rewardedAd.show(MainActivity.this, adCallback);
```

Test real mobile: Android 6.0, Huawei p8 Lite

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```

Tried to downgrade `com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads`, but it doesn't work

What is the problem?

*Edits*

Log:

```
E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(222)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/Ads: Invalid event ID: null
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this first part here in case it can help anybody else

You first need to detach the Webview:

```
webViewPlaceholder.removeView(myWebView);
myWebView.removeAllViews();
myWebView.destroy();
```

Try Something Like that, any other help you need you can just shout

*Edits*

Try something like this as the errors indicate there is a problem with the adview

```
public void onDestroy()
{
    adView.removeAllViews();
    adView.destroy();
    super onDestroy();
}
```

Add this to your oncreateM

```
mobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
    }
});
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don’t have webView in the application

Comment: Ads open in a webview, loaded from the API, Is the Above error codes all you recieve? post your logcat so we can get a better picture of the problem, Also check your layout where you load the ads into the layout

Comment: the reward ad don't have adView

Comment: This code is only suitable for banner ad, but not for reward ad.

Comment: The error You posted  indicates obviously that thier is a problem with the views your ads are showing in, you need to add a dedicated view/views for your ads

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and message : 
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.

In my case, it was because the code of mainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    finish();
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

"finish();" in the code makes app "finish" if ad video closed.
After deleting that one line, my app worked fine.